# How to extract lowest binding energy from thousand Vina dock log files and put in a txt file using python?

Tags: python, database, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

I have executed >1000 drug molecules in a Vina docking study. Now I have >1000 log files that contain the top ten binding scores for every compound in a log file for each. I want to extract only the lowest binding energy from each log file and get it as an output.txt file which must contain drug ID (file Name) in first column and lowest binding energy in second column. Can anybody show me the python script for this kind of workflow?

Output file is just look like this, I want to extract the lowest energy value that is the first negaitve value (Ex: -3.7 kcal/mol) in the present example. There are >1000 this kind log files in a folder. I want to extract the lowest energy value from all the log files and make it asx: a vector for further analysis.

```
Ex:
#################################################################
# If you used AutoDock Vina in your work, please cite:          #
#                                                               #
# O. Trott, A. J. Olson,                                        #
# AutoDock Vina: improving the speed and accuracy of docking    #
# with a new scoring function, efficient optimization and       #
# multithreading, Journal of Computational Chemistry 31 (2010)  #
# 455-461                                                       #
#                                                               #
# DOI 10.1002/jcc.21334                                         #
#                                                               #
# Please see http://vina.scripps.edu for more information.      #
#################################################################

WARNING: The search space volume > 27000 Angstrom^3 (See FAQ)
Output will be 1_out.pdbqt
Detected 4 CPUs
Reading input ... done.
Setting up the scoring function ... done.
Analyzing the binding site ... done.
Using random seed: -2146285232
Performing search ... done.
Refining results ... done.

mode |   affinity | dist from best mode
     | (kcal/mol) | rmsd l.b.| rmsd u.b.
-----+------------+----------+----------
   1         -3.7      0.000      0.000
   2         -3.6     18.479     19.190
   3         -3.6      3.437      4.976
   4         -3.6      1.802      2.411
   5         -3.6      2.650      3.645
   6         -3.5      2.071      3.134
   7         -3.5      2.069      3.501
   8         -3.4      1.638      2.141
   9         -3.4      1.617      2.511
  10         -3.3     18.549     19.217
Writing output ... done.
```

I tried the python os modul following other people's scripts, but couldn't get what I need.

This was the script I followed so far,

```
import os
import os.path
import glob
import itertools
import collections
import pprint
import sys
import fnmatch


#get path of current dir

mypath = os.getcwd()

print ("\nDirectory path detected \n")


#get compound name

comp_name = sys.argv[1]


#read all filenames in the dir

file_list = os.listdir(mypath)


#collecting the total number of log files in the directory.

num_files = len(glob.glob1(mypath,"*log*.txt"))
print('There are',num_files, 'log files in the current directory\n\n')


#looking for Binding affinity

for file_name in file_list:


    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file_name, '*'+comp_name+'*.txt'):
        with open(os.path.join(mypath, file_name), "r") as src_file:
                        
            for line in src_file:
                try:
                    if '-+' in line:                                                    #looking for binding affinity table
                        nextline = next(src_file)
                        value = nextline[nextline.find("-")+0:].split()[0]                  #split at '-' and print binding affinity including '-'
                        
                except IndexError:
                    continue

print("The Binding Affinity of "+comp_name+" is : "+value+"\n")
```

Comment: `I want to extract the lowest energy value` When you say "lowest," do you mean "closest to zero" or "closest to negative infinity?"

Comment: Dear Nick, In this study I want to get the highest negative value. In my example, it is -3.7 kcal/mol.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this, and I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out the purpose of `comp_name`, and how it relates to the drug ID. Could you clarify this aspect?

Comment: Dear Nick, I Just tried the script grabed from somebody elses script and trying to make a one for me. You can propose a correction. I am jsut a beginner for python.